# Dovecot export > import to another server

Tags: email, import, mail-server, dovecot

I have a dump from one mail server where is Dovecot. I received e-mail data dump in format:

```
- mail@example.com
- - .Drafts
- - - cur
- - - new
- - - tmp
- - - dovecot.index.log
- - - dovecot.uidlist
- - - maildirfolder
- - .Junk
- - - the same as Drafts
- - .Sent
- - etc...
- mail2@example.com
- - ...
```

Now, on the second server I´ve created mail addresses and I need to import those data there (I´ve mapped those e-mail addresess into Outlook if it will be easier to do).

Then I have a SSH access directly to the server, so if I take this dump and copy it into webserver, it´s possible too.

Is there anybody who did it? I tried to searched but no clue how to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `dsync` utility that can secure populate mailboxes between servers.

More information can be found here http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Tools/Dsync